# PHP Array Manipulation/Rearrangement

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp

I have the following array:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [User] => Array
            (
                [firstname] => Chris
                [lastname] => Willis
            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [User] => Array
            (
                [firstname] => Test
                [lastname] => Willis
            )

    )
   ...
```

I need it to be transformed into a structure similar to this:

```
Array
{
   'Chris-Willis' => 0
   'Test-Willis' => 1
   ....
```

What are some array functions to help to do this?

So it needs to be:

```
  firstname-lastname => id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CakePHP has the [Set::combine()](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/set.html#Set%3a%3acombine) method to help with such situations.

I'm assuming that you want the array values to be the database ID of the user, rather than the array index.

```
$users = $this->User->find('all', array(
  'fields' => array('id', 'firstname', 'lastname'),
));
$usersMap = Set::combine(
  $users,
  array('%1$s-%2$s', '{n}.User.firstname', '{n}.User.lastname') // sprintf() formatting
  '{n}.User.id',
);
```

Comment: thanks that's what I was looking for, i knew it existed somewhere

Answer (score 2):

```
$grouped = array();
foreach ($users as $i => $user) {
    $grouped["{$user['User']['firstname']}-{$user['User']['lastname']}"] = $i;
}
```

---

If the array is exactly as shown above, this should also do it:

```
$grouped = array_combine(array_map(function ($u) { return join('-', current($u)); }, $users), array_keys($users));
```

Comment: I was hoping to use a more elegant approach, like array-flip and set:extract in cakephp, but I can do the foreach if necessary

Comment: Added a more functional approach too. Not sure if that's really "more elegant" though... :)

Comment: yeah maybe you're right, i guess the readability drops with that approach too, thx +1

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach $original_array as $key=>$temp
{

    $some_other_array[$temp['USER']['firstname']."-".$temp['USER']['lastname']] = $key;
}
```

Comment: maybe the best way is to combine the first and last name in your sql with something like CONCAT_WS

Answer (score 0):

The following code should do the trick

//$names is the name of your array

`$namesId = array();`

`foreach ($names as $k=>$v)`
`{`

`$temp = $v["User"]["firstname"] . "-" . $v["User"]["lastname"];`
`$namesId[$temp] = $k;`

`}`